# Move changes from up-to-date Git repository to an older version of the repository

Tags: git, github

I have 2 repositories in different networks (intranets).
I want to copy the changes from the new repository to the old one including new branches, tags and file changes.

I thought of saving the `git diff` between every new-repo's branch and old-repo's branch and save common ancestors commits between branches to restore the topology of the new-repo (in case of new branches in new-repo).

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually use `git bundle` for such a workflow. It allows to transfer objects that are usually transferred by `fetch` - and thus also `pull` - via an archive that you can transfer over any medium you want.